# Flutter: StreamBuilder not returning my stream using Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to return cards that display building data from the Firebase database. 
The data was created & stored in the database under the uid of the user that inputted the building data through the app using a ModalBottomSheet.

I'm using a Streamprovider to generate a **`building_card.dart`** (StatelessWidget) template with data from Firebase that gets displayed in a **`building_card_list.dart`** file, which is a StatefulWidget and returns a ListView.builder that returns the **`building_card.dart`** templates. That BuildingList class then gets shown in the **`home_screen.dart`** as a child from an Expanded Widget.

The problem is, that it just never shows anything and I've tried everything to retrieve the data from Firebase and generate that list of cards.

Here's snippets from my code:

**home_screen.dart**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService authService = AuthService();
  Widget addBuildingSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return AddBuildingSheetCode();
  }

  Widget addProblemPickerSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return AddProblemPickerSheetCode();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    return StreamProvider<List<BuildingDataModel>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().buildings,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff131517),
        body: SafeArea(
          bottom: false,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              Expanded(
                flex: 30,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child: BuildingList()),
```

**building_card_list.dart**

```
class BuildingList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BuildingListState createState() => _BuildingListState();
}

class _BuildingListState extends State<BuildingList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final building = Provider.of<List<BuildingDataModel>>(context) ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: building.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return BuildingCard(buildings: building[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**building_card**

```
class BuildingCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final BuildingDataModel buildings;
  BuildingCard({this.buildings});

  final buildingImage = AssetImage('assets/images/building1.png');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
```

**building_data_model**

```
class BuildingDataModel {
  final String userUid;
  final String buildingName;
  final int buildingRooms;
  final String buildingLocation;
  final String buildingType;
  final String userEmail;

  BuildingDataModel({
    this.buildingName,
    this.buildingRooms,
    this.buildingLocation,
    this.buildingType,
    this.userEmail,
    this.userUid,
  });
}
```

**DatabaseService.buildings**

```
Stream<List<BuildingDataModel>> get buildings {
    return buildingCollection
        .document(uid)
        .collection('buildings')
        .snapshots()
        .map(_buildingListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

If you can help, I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong! If you need more info, let me know too...
It's the first app I've ever worked on as I'm new to coding and updating user data using a stream provider that takes data input from Firebase has been the bane of my existence in the past week...

thanks in advance!

Comment: You should post more of your code, for example, your `BuildingDataModel` class and your `DatabaseService.buildings`

Comment: Done, please check the edits.

Comment: I would use `Consumer` in building_card_list.dart. Check this link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#consumer. I think that `BuildingList` just runs once and at that time the list of buildings is empty. Actually maybe it's better to use consumer in  `HomeScreen`, that way you make sure that list of buildings is "ready".

Comment: Thanks! I've made it work using another person's tutorial, but after having searched for a fix for so long, I'll definitely look into this. I neeeed to understand what went right this time to avoid such a waste of time in the future. Thank you